# Writing an array of arrays to a text file in java?

Tags: java, file, save

I create an array with 10 instances of a class which is statsArray and within each of the instances I have another array with data. I want to write this to a text file to save the data  but its keeps giving me an error. numbersarray is an array of strings which is what i trying to copy the numbers in statsArray to

```
private void saveData(){
    try{


    for(int i = 0;i < statsArray.length;i++){
        numbersArray[i] = "";
        for(int j = 0;j < statsArray[i].getValues()[j];j++){
        numbersArray[i] += statsArray[i].getValues()[j];
        }   

    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("SavedData.txt"));
    for(int i = 0;i < numbersArray.length;i++){
       // for(int j = 0; j < statsArray[i].getValues()[j];j++) { 
        bw.write(numbersArray[i] + " ");
        bw.newLine();
        //}
    }
    bw.close();
```

Comment: "keeps giving me an error." What error?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Before I'll replay, do you want after to load data from the same file? And, please, add your exception

Comment: what is the error? what is the output? what is getValues()? Please post a self-contained example with the minimal code that reproduces the problem, so we don't have to guess what does getValues() do and whether it's fault of the first for or the second for.

Comment: Also, "for(int j = 0;j < statsArray[i].getValues()[j];j++){" change it to: "for(int j = 0;j < statsArray[i].getValues().length;j++){"

Comment: Also, it's enough to invoke statsArray[i].getValues() once in the outer for, so it will be run only i times.

Comment: fess - yes i want to load this data afterwords for the same file

Comment: ignis - I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and get values if the method from the other class that return the array of values i want to use

Comment: use `GSON` technique. It's really easy to convert your Arrays to String, like: `gson.toGson(yourObject); ... and on load: gson.fromGson(yourString, yourObject.class);` Its fast and no validation from your side.

Answer (score 3):

Would this approach be better ?

Loops through each instance of MyObject in the statsArray then loops through each string in the instance's numberArray and appends it to the buffered writer.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("SavedData.txt"));
for (MyObject mo : statsArray)
{
    for (String value : mo.getValues()) 
    {
        bw.write(value + " ");
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because statsArray is an array of a different class and numbersArray is part of this class

Comment: Ah right, misunderstood the code there, changed it to loop over the array in the getValues() call.
To get this to work with different class types in the statsArray, you could always cast to a super class if possible which has the getValues() function.

Comment: It actually returns an array of doubles but i tried changing string to double and it doesn't give me any errors it just doesn't write anything to the file now

Comment: Oh don't worry i just changed a couple of things earlier in the program and this got it workingg thanks

Comment: Problem is, I did not know the types you are dealing with, these need to be in the question. Not sure if you need to convert to a string first before adding it to the buffered writer.
When debugging, does the value get assigned correctly as it's looping over the array of doubles ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j = 0;j < statsArray[i].getValues()[j];j++){
    numbersArray[i] += statsArray[i].getValues()[j];
}
```

`statsArray[i].getValues()[j]` can be out of bounds.

You should write it as follows;

```
int[] values = statsArray[i].getValues();
for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
```

Comment: i tries this but i still get out of bound exception

Comment: @user1779821: Do the statArray and numbersArray have same length?

Comment: @user1779821: How are you defining those arrays? Also please post the stack trace.

Comment: statArray and numbersArray have the same length. they are defined earlier in the program like this

Comment: private Stats[] statsArray = new Stats[10];
     private String[] numbersArray = new String[10];

Answer (score 0):

Where do you allocate numbersArray? You must do

```
numbersArray= new String[statsArray.length]
```

before the first for loop.